# Temporarily modify the environment configuration for aws lambda function using java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to test my aws lambda function, where I am trying to invoke it from the java code like this
`

public static void invokeLambdaFunction() {

```
    final String functionArn =

            "Mylambdafunction";

    lambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()

           .region(REGION).build();

    final InvokeRequest invokeRequest = InvokeRequest.builder()

            .functionName(functionArn).build();

    final InvokeResponse invokeResult = lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest);

    final String responseJson = new String(invokeResult.payload().asUtf8String());

    LOGGER.info("Lambda function response: " + responseJson);`
```

The lambda function is configured by a YAML file along with the environment variables. Now for my testing purposes I need the values of those environment variables according to my test scenarios.

So how do I set the environment variables through Java code so that it reads the variables values provided by me but doesn't changes it's original configuration.

(Please do not provide a solution pertaining to changing the lambda function code).

I tried UpdateFunctionConfigurationRequest class of awsSdk, but that will change the value permanently.  So need a solution that either changes the environment values till execution time or reads it without setting values.